# What is the purpose of chamois cream?

Tags: chamois

I've seen it advertised but never used it, what's it for? Is it effective ?

Comment: Perhaps a good question for the Terminology Index: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index

Comment: @Dustin - Good idea, I've added an entry for [chamois](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/5154#5154) that also includes this.

Answer (score 5):

Chamois cream is useful if one is getting chafing from rubbing inside a pair of shorts. I've found it useful in high humidity.

Comment: Does Vaseline or anything common household items work to substitute?

Comment: @uosɐſ - I've heard that petroleum-based products like vaseline can break down lycra. Can anyone else substantiate this?